# How to perform code background downloads?

Tags: ios, swift, download, background

I'm developing an app which requires to download a big amount of data the first time it starts (around 1gb of images). Currently I'm using the library [MZDownloadManager](https://github.com/mzeeshanid/MZDownloadManager) to perform the downloads. The library implements the background modes for the downloads and I've even set it into the capabilities of my target. Basically I have this scenario :

- I call an API which gives me a json
- I save all the data in Core Data
- I save all the urls of images to be downloaded in an array
- I save Core Data
- I start the downloads

  - I download 1 item at a time
  - When an item is finished, I save the local path in Core Data and remove it from the array of urls
  - I start the new download
- When everything is completed, I show the UI hiding the progress bar

I want to give the user the possibility to put the app in background while the downloads are performed. It works pretty well on Simulator, but not on the device. I think on the Simulator works because of the big amount of memory of the Mac. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: You can profile the app and see if it's using too much CPU or memory. I know there is a limit on how much work you can do on each background call and perhaps that is the issue. Fyi there is another download manager here if that one has a bug.

https://github.com/Gurpartap/Cheapjack

Answer (score 0):

The `NSURLSession` class supports background file downloads. It will download your files even if your app gets terminated, and will re-launch you in the background once the download is completed if need be.

Answer (score 0):

To support background downloads, you must configure your `NSURLSession` object . To configure the session, you must first create a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object and set several properties to appropriate values. You then pass that configuration object to the appropriate initialization method of `NSURLSession` when creating your session.

To creating a configuration object that supports background download is as follows:

- First create configuration object using  `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`: method of `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.
- Configure any other properties like `sessionSendsLaunchEvents` and   `discretionary` of configuration object as appropriate.
- Use the configuration object to create your `NSURLSession` object

**Example:-**

```
 let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("bgSessionConfiguration")
    configuration.discretionary = true
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true //default true
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```